# Canvas rectangle with 3D effect border

Tags: html, canvas

[image: Canvas_Border]

(Refer to image)
First part of image shows div with raised borders(using -webkit-box-shadow,box-shadow properties). I want to give same effect to rectangle drawn using HTML5 canvas element.
Is it any way to acieve this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's possible, try something like this:

```
context.rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
context.fillStyle = 'white';
context.shadowColor = 'black';
context.shadowBlur = 25;
context.shadowOffsetX = 10;
context.shadowOffsetY = 10;
context.fill();
```

**[Working Example](http://jsbin.com/eqakot/2/edit)**